# Extract properties file from JAR dependency and use it in own classpath

Tags: java, maven, jar, properties

I want to use a small program as a dependency in my Maven project. This program is configured by a properties file which can be edited before its execution. So far I have added the dependency as JAR in a local repository.

Now I want to make that dependency's properties file accessible in my own superior classpath, i.e. in `myprogram/src/main/resources/config/myprogram.properties` and **not** in `myprogram/local-repository/com/example/mydependency/mydependency.jar/mydependency.properties`.

I tried to modify the part of the code where the path for the properties file is defined:

```
public example() {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = example.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/myprogram.properties");
    prop.load(input);

    ...

}
```

I also deleted the original properties file of the dependency before adding it to my local repository.

The whole program is working, but not as expected. Strangely, neither my new properties file in `/src/main/resources/config` nor the old one in the `mydependency.jar` is used. It seems that some kind of default properties file is put into my final fat JAR. But I cannot find its source anywhere - even when I try to debug it. That default properties file just seems to appear out of nowhere.

Now, how can I properly move the dependency's properties file to my own classpath?

And where could this default properties file appear from?

Is this an issue with Maven or with the source code itself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds very strange: your local maven repository is located in `myprogram/local-repository`?

Comment: *Is this an issue with Maven or with the source code itself?* my point of view: it's an issue of your concept. Creating a properties file and putting it in the class path isn't an effort that takes hours... create a file with a name different from the one in the dependency and put it in the class path of your app ( arc/main/resources )

Comment: @JimHawkins Yes, my local maven repository is in ``myprogram/local-repository``. So you mean I should create a new properties file, that overwrites the one in the dependency? How can I achieve this or how does the program know that I want to overwrite that particular file, respectively?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    public static String getValueFromDependencyProps(ClassLoader cl, String propertiesFile, String key) throws IOException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(cl.getResourceAsStream(propertiesFile));
    String value = prop.getProperty(key);

    if (value == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    else
        return value;
}
```

And then:

```
String value = getValueFromDependencyProps(YourDependencyClass.class.getClassLoader(), "your.properties", key);
```

Tested and working. With that I'm able to access any properties file from an external Maven dependency (using one of its classes, `YourDependencyClass`, to reach it).